# SQL Server Error: "maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3" with subselect syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, linked-server

Trying to run a cross-server update:

```
UPDATE asilive.Contoso.dbo.lsipos
SET PostHistorySequencenNmber = (
    SELECT TransactionNumber 
    FROM Transactions 
    WHERE Transactions.TransactionDate = 
         asilive.CMSFintrac.dbo.lsipos.TransactionDate)
```

Gives the error:

```
Server: Msg 117, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
The number name 'asilive.Contoso.dbo.lsipos' contains more than 
the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.
```

What gives?

---

**Note:** Rearranging the query into a <strike>less readable</strike> join form:

```
UPDATE asilive.Contoso.dbo.lsipos
SET PostHistorySequenceNumber = B.TransactionNumber
FROM cmslive.Contoso.dbo.lsipos A
    INNER JOIN Transactions B
    ON A.TransactionDate = B.TransactionDate
```

does not give an error.

### See also

- [SQL Server Error: maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3. with join syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152133/sql-server-error-maximum-number-of-prefixes-the-maximum-is-3-with-join-syntax/7152149#7152149)
  (*Deals with join syntax; this question deals with sub-select syntax*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is just the way it is.  You can't have more than three prefixes, so you have to use an aliases when you go over 3 (mainly when joining to other servers).  It's been that way since Sql Server 7 (and maybe before I can't remember on 6.5).

If you want to make your code more readable when using aliases, specify a more meaningful alias which will make it a lot easier to follow.

Example:

```
SELECT 

production_accounting_clients.[ClientName]

FROM Production.Accounting.dbo.Clients production_accounting_clients
```

Comment: My select doesn't have a problem with a four-part prefix, the update does. And the `update` doesn't allow an alias. So i'm still curious to see a working syntax.

Comment: You can use alias with updates.  Update tn set tn.x=y from tableName tn