# SQL Server Error: maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3. with join syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, linked-server

Trying to run a cross-server update:

```
UPDATE ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions
SET ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions.VarianceAmount=Variances.VarianceAmount
FROM ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions
    INNER JOIN Variances
    ON ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions.SessionGUID = Variances.SessionGUID
WHERE ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions.VarianceAmount <> Variances.VarianceAmount
```

Gives the error:

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
The number name 'ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions' contains 
more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.
```

What gives?

---

### See also

- [SQL Server Error:  "maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3" with subselect syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404503/sql-server-error-maximum-number-of-prefixes-the-maximum-is-3-with-subselect)
  (*Deals with sub-select syntax; this question deals with join syntax*)

---

**Unimportant research:**

i tried randomly aliasing things to `s`:

```
UPDATE ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions s
SET s.VarianceAmount=Variances.VarianceAmount
FROM ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions s
    INNER JOIN Variances
    ON s.SessionGUID = Variances.SessionGUID
WHERE s.VarianceAmount <> Variances.VarianceAmount
```

But that doesn't work:

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
The number name 'ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions' contains 
more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.
```

Hamlin suggested added brackets:

```
UPDATE [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions
SET [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions.DisciplineVarianceAmount=DisciplineVariances.VarianceAmount
FROM [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions
    INNER JOIN DisciplineVariances
    ON [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions.SessionGUID = DisciplineVariances.SessionGUID
WHERE [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions.DisciplineVarianceAmount <> DisciplineVariances.VarianceAmount
```

but that doesn't work:

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
The number name 'ASILIVE.CustomerManagementSystem.dbo.Sessions' contains
more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really like a lot of typing? :-)

```
UPDATE s
  SET s.DisciplineVarianceAmount = v.VarianceAmount
  FROM [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions AS s
  INNER JOIN dbo.Variances AS v
  ON s.SessionGUID = v.SessionGUID
  AND s.VarianceAmount <> v.VarianceAmount;
```

Take note that you may want to describe what to do here if either variance amount is currently `NULL`.

Comment: i do prefer helpful table and column names. Contrast that with AS/400's 6-character column names, of which two are reserved - leaving you four character column names (e.g. `PFNMCN`)

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I guess your experience with AS/400 should explain your love for long names. And it must be very fortunate for your typing abilities, because at times when your thoughts flow rapidly, you want to type fast, and having to type long identifiers makes you acquire fast typing sooner. :)

Comment: BTW you don't need the alias in the set staments on the left of the equals sign as it MUST be a field in the table listed in the update. SET DisciplineVarianceAmount = v.VarianceAmount  will work as well.

Comment: @HLGEM While true, I prefer to be explicit over saving two keystrokes. Self-documenting code, especially for users not familiar with SQL Server's proprietary update syntax, pays for itself.

Comment: I find the other form makes more sense to me and is easier to read. Apparently so does Microsoft as they generally do not use the alias in their examples in Books Online which is where I learned the form I use. But both forms work perfectly well and their use is a personal preference or company style.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "I prefer to" rather than "you should." :-)

Comment: BoL is very poor in documenting the `UPDATE FROM` syntax; hence i could not make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Often times, you need to add brackets, at a minimum, surrounding your Linked Server Name.

```
[ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions
```

**EDIT** -  Try this in addition

```
UPDATE S
SET DisciplineVarianceAmount = Variances.VarianceAmount
FROM [ASILIVE].[CustomerManagementSystem].dbo.Sessions as S
    INNER JOIN Variances ON S.SessionGUID = Variances.SessionGUID
WHERE S.VarianceAmount <> Variances.VarianceAmount
```

Comment: i had *no* idea you could use an alias in the `UPDATE` portion. And while you offered an (incorrect) answer first, i'm going to give it to Aaron. Not just because his (correct) answer came before your update, but because his version points out that you can continue to use the alias in the `SET` portion (which is what i was desperately trying to do). And while you need the rep more than he does, in fairness he had the correct answer first.

Comment: +1 if, for no other reason (other than also being correct), than it's tough when someone else's nearly identical/simultaneous answer gets chosen.

Comment: Same to you! I'm tempted to remove my answer since it contains some redundant information, but I have seen this error eliminated with the first portion of my answer. May be useful to passersby. Referencing linked servers can feel syntactically-random sometimes

Comment: I think that would only occur if you've actually named your linked server something like `foo.bar`; having said that, it probably is quite common to reference a FQDN or even an IP or web address, e.g. I've seen linked servers in the form `foo.bar.com\instance`...